# Show that the Taylor series for the principal part of $\log(1+z)$ converges absolutely for $|z|\le1$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, absolute-convergence

Show that the Taylor series for the principal part of $\log(1+z)$ converges absolutely for $|z|\le1$

the Taylor series for

$$\log(1+z)=z-\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{3}-\frac{z^4}{4}+......\sum _{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}z^{n}}{n}$$

how to prove the principal part converges absolutely for $|z|\le 1$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct radius of convergence for $\ln(1+x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356517/what-is-the-correct-radius-of-convergence-for-ln1x)

Comment: It should be this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/621211/290189

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uniform and absolute convergence of complex series to $\log(1+z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621211/uniform-and-absolute-convergence-of-complex-series-to-log1z)

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of the questions at those links.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody can prove that because it is false. At $z=-1$, the series diverges, since it is equal to$$-1-\frac12-\frac13-\frac14-\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Note that $f(z)=\log(1+z)$ is analytic for $|z|<1$ (why?) and not analytic at $z=-1$. So, the radius of convergence of $f$ is $R=1$.

We can easily see that, thus, the principal part of the Laurent series converges uniformly on $|z|<1$.

Comment: No, not on the whole open disc.